# jQuery ajax if var is null post another data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      cookieanimalid =($.cookie("cookieanimal"));

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "/myurl/",
          data: {cookieanimalid},
          success: function (data){

              if (!$.trim(data)) {
                  animalid = $("div.dropdown-menu a:first-child").attr("value");

                  $("#show").html(data);

              }else {
                  $("#show").html(data);

              }
          }
      });

  });
```

What i am trying to do is if data is empty post in the same div another data where data is = animalid. He post me just the value of animalid but i needanothers. Maybe the sintax is not right? Maybe is to make an if else statament with var an after that post ajax data? Can someone help me?

Comment: Remove the if/else, instead: `animalid = $("div.dropdown-menu a:first-child").attr("value"); $("#show").html(data || animalid);`

Comment: Also, why are you wrapping your data into an object? `{cookieanimalid}` you should stringify it `JSON.stringify({cookieanimalid})`

Comment: I keep trying to wrap my head around this part of your question : `if data is empty post in the same div another data where data is = animalid. He post me just the value of animalid but i needanothers.` but I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney because i need jus the value of that and this is a number

Comment: @Christian sorry your english is making it hard to actually understand the problem.

Comment: @Christian try and explain by making cases in points.

Comment: @techie_28 yes i know sorry for my english. I have a variable cookieanimalid  and animalid and i need to post it in the url jut one of that. I need that one that is not null.

Comment: @Christian you mean you need to send either `cookieanimalid` or the `animalid` in the Ajax Request when either one of them is not null?

Comment: @techie_28 i need to send data to the div but before i send it i must to check wich one is not null cookieanimalid or animalid. If cookieanimalid is empy than use animalid ind ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the if/else in success then instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/petbook/PetBook/",
    data: {
        cookieanimalid
    },
    success: function(response) { /* <-- this was called data, it is not related to data above, you could all this anything */
        animalid = $("div.dropdown-menu a:first-child").attr("value"); 
        /* here we're saying if there is data, use that and if not, use animalid */
        $("#show").html(response || animalid);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Do you mean like this?

```
cookieanimalid = ($.cookie("cookieanimal"));

animalid = $("div.dropdown-menu a:first-child").attr("value");

if (!cookieanimalid) { /* if no cookieanimalid, then show animalid */
    $("#show").html(animalid);
} else { /* else go and get the data */
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/myurl/",
        data: cookieanimalid,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#show").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

You mean like this?

```
cookieanimalid = ($.cookie("cookieanimal"));

animalid = $("div.dropdown-menu a:first-child").attr("value");

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/myurl/",
    data: cookieanimalid || animalid, /* send whichever is true, cookieanimalid first choice */
    success: function(data) {
        $("#show").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes but what is with  data: {cookieanimalid}? your code make the same thing as my with if else. What i am trying to do is to use it with var if else and then send the data if you understand what i mean?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: your code returns me the value for example :1 intro div #show but if data is not empy it returns me the cookieanimalid in the div and behinde this cookieanimalid is an code that returns me more value. Thats why i need if cookieanimalid is null that use animalid into data.

Comment: Aaahhhhh - you're looking at it wrong... I'll update my answer

Comment: sorry for my english maybe this is the problem why you haven't understood what i mean

Comment: Thx for your help but i need to check if the variable is empy and if variable is null and after that to post it as data. I don't need to pot variable i need to post data.

Comment: @Christian than you just need to update `data: cookieanimalid,` with         `data: {cookieanimalid}`, in the latest updated answer?

Comment: @techie_28 this is not what i am looking for. What i need to check if cookieanimalid is empy than use animalid as data: {animalid} in ajax request to post it to my url in the div #show

Comment: data: cookieanimalid || animalid  its ok but how should i us then       $_POST["cookieanimalid || animalid"]?

Comment: thats why i said that with if statement that check wich one is not empy. Maybe **var notempty= cookieanimalid || animalid;** and then **data: notempy**  in axaj request and in php  **$_POST["notempty"];**  ?

Comment: my answer was that what i needed thx of lot and sorry for bother.